# Loading node-orm2 through a promise, causes CWD and module not found

Tags: node.js, express, promise, node-orm2

I have a function which loads my node-orm models:

```
function(server, connectionString){
    server.use(orm.express(connectionString,  {
        define: function (db, models, next) {
            loadIdeaDomain(db)
            next()          
        }   
    }))
    return this
}
```

There is another piece of middleware (passport) that needs  to run after the node-orm models are loaded...  BUT the aync nature is driving me crazy.  Can I convert the above into a promise OR wait for it to execute before proceeding?

### Update converting loadIdeaDomain to a promise

```
var loadIdeaDomain = function(db){
    var ideaDomainPath = './idea-domain/idea-domain.js'
    console.log('loading ' + ideaDomainPath)
    var qLoad = Q.nbind(db.load, db)
    return qLoad(ideaDomainPath).then(function(){
        console.log('THEN')
        definedModels = db.models

        _.each(_.keys(db.models), function(modelName) {
            makeQPromises(db.models[modelName], modelName)
        })
        return db.models
    }, function(e){
        console.log('ERR')
        console.log(e)

    })
}
```

This looks as though it will work, except I am getting an error:

> { [Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\Users\todd\Documents\web\nodeTest\trq\node_modules\q/.idea-domain/idea-domain.js']
>   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

so it looks as though this is traced back to the node-orm library module Utilities.js and this awesome function:

```
exports.getRealPath = function (path_str, stack_index) {
    var path = require("path"); // for now, load here (only when needed)
    var cwd = process.cwd();
    var err = new Error();
    var tmp = err.stack.split(/\r?\n/)[typeof stack_index !== "undefined" ? stack_index : 3], m;

    if ((m = tmp.match(/^\s*at\s+(.+):\d+:\d+$/)) !== null) {
        cwd = path.dirname(m[1]);
    } else if ((m = tmp.match(/^\s*at\s+module\.exports\s+\((.+?)\)/)) !== null) {
        cwd = path.dirname(m[1]);
    } else if ((m = tmp.match(/^\s*at\s+.+\s+\((.+):\d+:\d+\)$/)) !== null) {
        cwd = path.dirname(m[1]);
    }

    if (path_str[0] !== path.sep) {
        path_str = cwd + "/" + path_str;
    }
    if (path_str.substr(-1) === path.sep) {
        path_str += "index";
    }

    return path_str;
};
```

THis is the line that is the problem

```
path_str = cwd + "/" + path_str;
```

Comment: Are zou getting errors or something with this?

Comment: It works, but async II want to know when it completes so the rest of the  chain continues.  I am converting the loadIdeaDomain to a promise...  I will post an update

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to override the load method in ORM.js for this one spot  I redefined the method as:

```
var loadViaFullPath = function() {
    var files = _.flatten(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
    var cb    = function () {};

    if (typeof files[files.length - 1] == "function") {
        cb = files.pop();
    }

    var loadNext = function () {
        if (files.length === 0) {
            return cb();
        }

        var file = files.shift();

        try {
                    // NOTICE THE REMOVAL OF Utilities
            return require(file)(this, function (err) {
                if (err) return cb(err);

                return loadNext();
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            return cb(ex);
        }
    }.bind(this);

    return loadNext();
}
```

Then

```
var loadIdeaDomain = function(db){
    var ideaDomainPath = __dirname + '/idea-domain/idea-domain.js'
    console.log('loading ' + ideaDomainPath)

    db.load2 = loadViaFullPath

    var qLoad = Q.nbind(db.load2, db)
    return qLoad(ideaDomainPath).then(function(){
        _.each(_.keys(db.models), function(modelName) {
            makeQPromises(db.models[modelName], modelName)
        })
        return db.models
    })
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
    server.use(orm.express(connectionString,  {
        define: function (db, models, next) {
            loadIdeaDomain(db).then(function(models){
                definedModels = models
                next()
            })
        }   
    }))
```

### Update

not quite - it doesn't seem to capture and store prior to  moving on